# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' Java

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, mediapipe

I exported my Unity project and opened export in Android Studio.Used Mediapipe in project.Running my app and getting error.

```
*Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :mediapipe_android:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :unityLibrary*
```

Comment: Gradle is unable to find the `mediapipe_android` dependency. How did you add it to your project?

Comment: It was defined in unity library.In this way:(build:gradle(:unityLibrary))                                                   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'mediapipe_android', ext:'aar')
}